# Java - Matrix is singular

Tags: java, matrix, singular

I have this code:

```
OLSMultipleLinearRegression regression = new OLSMultipleLinearRegression();
double[] consumptions = new double[vec.size()];  
double[][] x = new double[(int) (trainPart * vec.size())][3];

 while (it_vec.hasNext() ) {
   Vector<Double> tmp = new Vector<Double>();
   tmp = it_vec.next();

   if (count < trainPart * (vec.size())) {
     consumptions[count] = tmp.get(0);
     x[count] = new double []{tmp.get(1), tmp.get(4), season(tmp.get(5))};
    } else {
       //do something else  
       }        
    count++;
 }

regression.newSampleData(consumptions, x);
double[] coeff = regression.estimateRegressionParameters();
```

I save electricity consumptions (double) into array `consumptions` in `while` cycle. Array `x`keeps three doubles, this: `x[count] = new double []{tmp.get(1), tmp.get(4), season(tmp.get(5))};`. `tmp.get(1)` is hour of the day, `tmp.get(4)` is 1.0 or 0.0 (1.0 if is weekend), `season(tmp.get(5))` return 1.0 or 0.0 (1.0 if there are winter months).
Error I get at the last line:  `matrix is singular`.

I know matrix is singular if determinant is zero but I have a lot of observations.
Does anyone know where the problem may be?
Thank you, Daniel

Comment: Have you actually checked that your matrix is _not_ singular?

Comment: I tried compute determinant with JAMA but I got error matrix isn't square. Then I tried compute inverse matrix but i got error: Matrix is rank deficient. My matrix can't be square matrix... I have a lot of consumptions but only 3 independent variables for linear regression. Matrix isn't square in documentation, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.5_Multiple_linear_regression .

Comment: The very idea of linear regression is to find a "best approximate" solution for linear problems where the regression matrix is not square, so this should not be the problem.
Could it be that you have to switch columns for rows i.e. to transpose your matrix x?